# Trouble changing the log level in RedHawk

Tags: redhawksdr

I am using RedHawk 2.1.2 and changing the log level through the IDE for devices or components seems to have no effect.  If I raise it to TRACE or ALL I still get only INFO and below.  If I lower it to WARN I still get INFO messages.  If I return to the Set Debug Level dialog it shows my choice, but this does not seems to effect the log messages that are displayed. I am using the default log configuration with log messages displayed to stdout.

I know it worked before at least with RedHawk 2.0.1.  Is this a known problem with 2.1.2 or is there some other issue that might cause it to ignore the level change?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this issue was resolved in REDHAWK 2.1.3

Comment: No releases beyond 2.1.2 are listed on the RedHawk Home and Download pages, but I see 2.2 on github with release notes.  Is it released and stable?

Comment: I am trying RH2.2.0 and it still seems to have this problem.  If I change log level to TRACE I get trace level logs from <component>.systemm.PropertySet (two per second) but none from my component's LOG_TRACE.  If I set level to TRACE, I get LOG_INFO's but no LOG_TRACE

Comment: BTW this issues applies to log levels in devices as well as components